# How to setup junction pointing 2x to contacts to delete child records when master is deleted?

Tags: junction-object

The contacts in our SF instance can give gifts from other contacts or receive gifts from contacts.

I need a way to represent who gave to whom and if a contact is deleted any record with the taker and giver fields that contain that contact also get deleted.

I can make a junction object with lookup fields but that won't automatically delete the records like it would with a mater detail field but I can't make 2 MD fields pointing to contacts in the same object.

What would I want to do?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? This site is not a code writing service. At it's base, all you need to do is write the appropriate `after delete` trigger on `Contact`.

Comment: Who mentioned code? How to set this up? That is what I am looking to learn. Is the answer that I need a trigger or process builder or can this be setup differently than what I wrote?

Answer (score 0):

A junction object MUST have two master-detail relationships. You cannot make a junction object with a lookup relationship.

I suggest you sketch or use another low tech mock up to identify your relationships, which objects & fields are involved, and what triggers & updates you require, then work with them in Schema Builder.

Comment: Not really true. Depending on your purpose a junction will work just fine via `Lookup`.

Comment: Let me try that again. :-)      "A junction object is a custom object with two master-detail relationships, and is the key to making a many-to-many relationship."          https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.fundamentals.meta/fundamentals/adg_relationships_many_relationship.htm

Comment: Yes I am aware of the most rigid definition.

Comment: Cool. Then we can agree the OP is not going to find the relevant documentation for what s/he is trying to do by looking at the junction object documentation and s/he may need to define the problem more broadly and change the key words in order to attract the right answer, right? It sounds like the OP may be relying on a cascading delete which exists in junction objects because they require master-detail relationships but which do not exist in lookup relationships.

Comment: It is about cascade delete. Completely unrelated to the term junction. Your answer doesn't really further the OP toward that end.